# Should I return Marionette view instances from view modules? ---require JS marionettee

Tags: requirejs, marionette

If I am using require JS with marionette and I have a module for view should I return an instance? (and why)

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning the View definition not an instance.

```
define(['marionette'], function (Marionette) {

    return Marionette.View.extend({

         onRender: function(){
          //something
         }
    });
});
```

Here is why, require evaluate the module once and then caches the result. so if you were to return the instance that would be the only instance ever created from that view, you wouldn't be able to create other instances.

I hope this answers your question.